# data appear and disapear when jquery loads

Tags: php, jquery

i have this code bellow and i have select options with `$menucompare` values .

```
<script>
  function displayVals() {
    var singleValues = $("#menucompare").val();
    $("#hiddenselect").attr("value", singleValues );
    $("p").html("Procent of: " + singleValues);
  }

  $("select").change(displayVals);
  displayVals();
</script>

<table width='100%' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
  <th>weeks</th>
  <th style="text-align: left; padding-left:5%;"><?php echo "<p></p>"; ?></th>
```

which i can get this value  (Procent of: $menucompare) . but the problem is when i select one option , the value appears right when jquery is loading , and when jquery is finished loading it disapears this (Procent of: $menucompare) , of course the variable $menucompare commes with the right value.

so i want even when jquery finished loading this value stays in the table . hope can get some fix for this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following script instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){
       $("select").change(function() { 
             displayVals(); 
       });
       displayVals();
  });

  function displayVals() {
    var singleValues = $("#menucompare").val();
    $("#hiddenselect").val(singleValues);
    $("p").html("Procent of: " + singleValues);
  }

</script>
```